# How to correctly write a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following directory structure

[image]

RawRepo contains a simple class:

```
class RawRepo:
    pass
```

**init**.py contains:

```
__all__ = ["RawRepo"]
```

And yap-analysis.py, my "main file", uses either of the following, but it doesn't work:

```
from yap import RawRepo
from yap import *
```

when I try to instantiate it, saying:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

How to make it actually work? I want `yap` to be the module, and `RawRepo` just one of its classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the class in `yap/init.py`:

```
from .RawRepo import RawRepo
```

Then you can import it in `yap-analysis.py` like this:

```
from yap import RawRepo
```

Note that you can group multiple classes in on module. You should also consider to rename the module to something like raw_repo to conform to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), "modules should have short, all-lowercase names."

Answer (score 0):

With the imports that you have, the class is called `RawRepo.RawRepo`, not `RawRepo` (the latter is the module).

Answer (score 0):

`RawRepo` is the module. `RawRepo.RawRepo` is the class, and what you should be instantiating.

Comment: But I don't want `RawRepo` to be a module, I want `yap` to be the module and `RawRepo` just one of its classes.

Comment: In that case, forget the directory structure and just have a plain `yap.py`.

Comment: I will be adding more classes as the project evolves, and I really want to have it structured.

Answer (score 0):

in `__init__.py`

```
from RawRepo import *
```

then do in `yap-analysis.py`

```
from yap import *

r = RawRepo()
```

Comment: +1, but this looks ugly. How should I make the directory structure such that I would use `from yap import RawRepo` and `r = RawRepo()` ?

Comment: Along with the `__all__` assignment?

Comment: @Skeetch Note that you don't need `__all__`, its main use (apart from explicitness about module contents, which is moot if you insist on having just one class per file) is limiting the damage of `from ... import *`. Which you shouldn't use anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that Python compiler knows a **.py** file as a **module**.

You named both the python module file and the name of Class as RawRepo. This idiom basically comes from Java world, and isn't very Pythonic ...

you can change in `__init__` file to import **contents** of a module ..

Comment: It's less about idioms and more about functionality. Python has a concept of modules, and each module can contain a number of classes (among other things). Java has no such concept and directly uses classes as package contents and things to import.

Comment: well, I meant naming same thing for both source file and ClassName is more common in Java than Python ..

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but that's not the core of the issue.